# Thunderbird Duplicate messages

Tags: thunderbird, duplicate

I see duplicate messages in my Thunderbird where there are a number of active email accounts .. I have to delete every hour a long list of duplicate mails from each account inbox .. yesterday I did a terminal reinstall ,  :

sudo apt-get install --reinstall Thunderbird

after successful install I see same duplicate mails being downloaded .. I left working on laptop during compacting so not to take chances .. note I have 26 GB worth email which I don't want to corrupt .. Ive taken backup yesterday .. help what to do to correct this duplicate email problem

Comment: Almost certainly due to account(s) settings. Need more info.

Comment: What other info required ?

Comment: Account settings.